# Adding UIView from class without frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to add a UIView from a function (in this case, within a statically built library) to a view without passing a frame for the view itself.

Paypal's library achieves this, and I was wondering how the implementation would go.

I don't want to change the root controller, I would just like to add my view over the current controller.

in the style of

```
[something addSubview:myNewView];
```

Where something is a view that I don't have access too.

Comment: Without passing a frame for which view — parent or child? And are you sure you mean to ask about the frame? It sounds like you might be more interested in finding the current topmost view controller and view than in frames.

Comment: I think this is more the functionality that I"m looking for. I would like to find the topmost view controller and then overlay over that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You simply use the default `init` method instead of `initWithFrame:`:

```
MyView *mySubview = [[MyView alloc] init];
[otherView addSubview:mySubview];
```

Note that this will result in a frame at origin (0/0) with zero size for mySubview and though it would be invisible. You could either specify the frame later, once you know it, or MyView can override the init method and pass a default frame to `[super initWithFrame:defaultFrame]`.

Answer (score 1):

While DrummberB's answer is correct, the view would not show up anywhere because a view initialized without a frame defaults to a frame of CGRectZero.  Sooner or later you will need to assign a frame to the view.